# Convert a function into an apply, sapply (data.frame)

Tags: r, dataframe, sapply

So I just built this function which basically takes two strings (a text, and a set of keywords). Then it has to find how many keywords are contained by the text string, if any. I been trying to apply the code on a data frame with no success.

Function is working:

```
something=function(text,keywords){
  kw = unlist(strsplit(keywords, ","))
  c=0
  for(i in length(kw)){
    if(grepl(kw[i],text)==0){
      c=c+1
    } else {c}
  }
  return(c)
}
```

Where if I imput:

```
> something("this planetarium is the shit","planetarium,amazing")
[1] 1
```

But what if my data frame was `df`

```
     keyword         text_clean
1    planetarium     Man this planetarium is the shit
2 musee,africain     rt lyonmangels reste encore places franceangels tour lyon organisons  investissons pme
```

My output expected is:

```
  df.1
1  1
2  0
```

Any insight? I was trying this code:

```
substng<-function(text, keywords){

  vector = laply(text,function(text,keywords){
    kw = unlist(strsplit(keywords, ","))
    c=0
    for(i in length(kw)){
      if(grepl(kw[i],text)==0){
        c=c+1
      } else {c}
    }
    return(c)
  })
  vector.df= as.data.frame(vector)
}

df <- read.table(header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, text = "keyword         text_clean
planetarium     'Man this planetarium is the shit'
musee,africain     'rt lyonmangels reste encore places franceangels tour lyon organisons  investissons pme'")

df$count = substng(df$text_clean,df$keyword)
```

Comment: `mapply(something, df$text_clean, df$keyword, USE.NAMES = FALSE)` should work. although I think you are `grepl(...)==0`'ing when you should be `grepl(...)==1`'ing

Comment: I tested that, `grepl(...)==0` where 0 is True.. but your mapply helped me solve my code. I've got my function running!
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think stri_count in the stringi package can accomplish this.

Use "pattern|amazing" as the pattern/regex.  Pipe = "or".

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringi/stringi.pdf

Comment: Ok thank you, it seems that would only replace my `for` loop with `grep`, which is good, does this means its going to do it for the whole `df`?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, yes.  From your original question, I thought you wanted an integer vector output of the number of times a keyword appears in each string in the data frame.  stri_count will give you this. grepl will give you a logical vector based on any keyword appearing in the string regardless of the number of times.